# how to make the number auto increment?

Tags: jquery

`<span id="shortfall" style="color:black">1</span>` views

is there a way to get this by jquery?

when the user refresh the page,the number auto  increment one(2,3,4.....). how to do it? thank you,

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you're up to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the Web Storage API it should be quite simple (you could also use `sessionStorage`, depending on what you're actually trying to achieve):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!localStorage.count) {
        localStorage.count = 0;   
    }
    localStorage.count++;
    var num = localStorage.count;
    $("#shortfall").text(num);
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNX9/). You could also use cookies, or you could do it server side (e.g. with a PHP session). I'm not entirely clear on whether you are intending the number to increment for each user, or a total for all users... if it's the latter, you're going to have to do it server side!

Answer (score 1):

If you stores the impression in the javascript localstorage variable, what you need to do is that,

1. Retrieves current impression in the database.
2. Add the current user impression to the existing impression so impression will keep on increasing.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COOKIE, LocalStorage or Database on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement a counter of impressions jquery will not help you, because JavaScript, and therefore jQuery runs on the client side, and even if you were to save the current number in a cookie and increment it on each page reload it would not be very useful because the number will always be 1 for a new user.